# Adding windows to a google container engine cluster

Tags: windows, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to add a Windows 2016 server to a Google Container Cluster so it can support both Windows and Linux Docker containers?  If so are there any written instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server is not yet supported on Google Container Engine.

Comment: Do you know when support will be added?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Kubernetes support for Windows is still in very early days.